# I want the acknowledge bit to be ignored during i2c communication in stm32f407vg

Tags: i2c, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubemx

I'm programming any integrated chip via stm32f407vg (chip zsc31050). I want to communicate between stm32 and zsc31050 via i2c communication. I using Keil and stm32cubemx for programing stm32. According to the datasheet of the chip during the first programing, this chip does not send acknowledge bit. the acknowledge bit does not follow after the slave address.so stm32 doesn't send any configuration bits. I want to change `stm32fxx_hal_i2c.c` library so that stm32 will ignore the acknowledge bit. What can I do about it?

Comment: stm32fxx_hal_i2c.c  lib  link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jz671nxjoXdL_wwUVpysT9TW5A17Fv1i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i2c communication waveform   :   https://drive.google.com/file/d/18YscVNUK2YU0btqWJWNwyKjVipGMLkct/view?usp=sharing